# django apache wsgi issue

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

i want open django server using apache and mod_wsgi.
i wrote down as below

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

and create django project and app and i add my bot in setting.py
and create virtual environment and using 
and add below code in seoultech/wsgi.py  /django = mydirctory/ seoultech=project/bot =app /

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/django')
sys.path.append('/home/django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "seoultech.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and cd /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf 
add code

```
WSGIDaemonProcess seoultech python-path=/home/django/seoultech=home/django
/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/seoultech/wsgi.py


<Directory /home/django/seoultech>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory
</VirtualHost>
```

but sudo apachectl-k start  i got error

```
'AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
/000default.conf:Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled
or defined by a module not included in the server configuration Action '-k
start' failed.The Apache error log may have more information.'
```

im looking forward to help

Comment: After you properly load/enable mod_wsgi, as the error indicates is the problem, you are missing a ``WSGIProcessGroup`` directive and are not configuring the Python virtual environment correctly. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 0):

Place WSGIDaemonProcess inside of VirtualHost to get rid of this error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess seoultech python-path=/home/django/seoultech=home/django
/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/seoultech/wsgi.py


<Directory /home/django/seoultech>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: sudo a2enmod wsgi?

Comment: ERROR:Module wsgi does not exist!

Comment: Please, google how to enable wsgi module for Apache.

Comment: sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load  , i can sudo a2enmod wsgi , but i got same error ...  i don't know reason